# How to create a new sql table from existing table with small calculations

Tags: sql, sqlite, case

I have a SQLite table like this:

| id | item | totalcost | sharedppl | paidby | second | third |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Lunch | 150 | 3 | Tom | Jack | Harry |
| 2 | Dinner | 200 | 2 | Jack | Harry |  |
| 3 | Drinks | 75 | 3 | Harry | Jack | Tom |

I want a new SQLite table to show share of each person. It needs to do the calculation to split the cost for each item between the people.

| item | Tom | Jack | Harry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lunch | 50 | 50 | 50 |
| Dinner | 0 | 100 | 100 |
| Drinks | 25 | 25 | 25 |

Please advise what query I need to run on sql to get this new table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression that calculates the share for each person:

```
SELECT item,
       CASE WHEN 'Tom' IN (paidby, second, third) THEN 1.0 * totalcost / sharedppl ELSE 0 END AS Tom,
       CASE WHEN 'Jack' IN (paidby, second, third) THEN 1.0 * totalcost / sharedppl ELSE 0 END AS Jack,
       CASE WHEN 'Harry' IN (paidby, second, third) THEN 1.0 * totalcost / sharedppl ELSE 0 END AS Harry
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=193ccc938f03a4b45f2fc3a4ae10313b).

Comment: I see the demo, but for some reason it doesn't work. I get an error:
++
Execution finished with errors.
Result: near "FROM": syntax error
At line 1:
++

Comment: @ukki then you are doing something wrong. Do you have a `,` before FROM, or another typo?

Comment: Thanks @forpas, I had extra `,`. This works perfect and shorter than the other solution. btw, if I don't want to put user name in CASE, then I should use Python to run these SQL commands? i just need some hint so that I can run same method on big data in my SQL table

Comment: @ukki SQLite does not have any pivot functionality, so if you want to write the code in pure sql you have to hardcode the names. With a programming language, you must construct the sql statement by concatenating all these CASE expressions for each name. I guess it will be a loop iterating for each name.

Answer (score 1):

One approach, using an unpivot followed by a pivot and aggregation:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT item, totalcost, paidby AS person FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT item, totalcost, second FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT item, totalcost, third FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    item,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN person = 'Tom' THEN 1 END) > 0
         THEN MAX(totalcost) / COUNT(person) ELSE 0 END AS Tom,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN person = 'Jack' THEN 1 END) > 0
         THEN MAX(totalcost) / COUNT(person) ELSE 0 END AS Jack,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN person = 'Harry' THEN 1 END) > 0
         THEN MAX(totalcost) / COUNT(person) ELSE 0 END AS Harry
FROM cte
GROUP BY item, id
ORDER BY id;
```

Side note: Your current table design is not normalized properly.  You can and should change it to the output you want here.

Comment: Thanks. This gives me the results I need.
But my list is big and I don't want to give person name in the SQL command (example: Tom, Jack). Any way to collect the person name from first table instead of giving it in my SQL command ?